# how to compare columns of two different data frames in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare two different columns of data frames in python

```
if abc['Company Name'] is  abc1['Full Legal Business Name']:
    if abc['Shop Name'] is abc1['Account Name']:
             if abc['Business Contact Email'] is abc1['Email Domain'] or abc['Business Contact Email'] is abc1['Business Email'] or abc['Business Contact Email'] is abc1['Customer Service Email']:
                            abc['Incremental_seller']='Y'
                            abc1['Incremental_seller'] ='Y'     

else:

           abc['Incremental_seller']='N'
           abc1['Incremental_seller']='N'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to picture since you are presenting it using text format.

But from what I understand, you want to compare two columns from your dataframe.

If so, you can simply use `numpy.where()` to do that.

`C = numpy.where('condition', x, y)`

`x` and `y` should be arrays.

Which means that `C` would be equal to `x` if condition returns `True` and `y` otherwise.

In your case:

```
abc['Incremental_seller'] = numpy.where((abc['Company Name'] == abc1['Full Legal Business Name']) and (abc['Shop Name'] == abc1['Account Name']) or (abc['Business Contact Email'] == abc1['Business Email']) or (abc['Business Contact Email'] == abc1['Customer Service Email']), ['Y'], ['N'])

abc1['Incremental_seller'] = numpy.where((abc['Company Name'] == abc1['Full Legal Business Name']) and (abc['Shop Name'] == abc1['Account Name']) or (abc['Business Contact Email'] == abc1['Business Email']) or (abc['Business Contact Email'] == abc1['Customer Service Email']), ['Y'], ['N'])
```

Granted that your dataframes: `abc` and `abc1` are of same length.

Comment: This is a vectorized approach which tends to be more useful on big dataframes. If you are parsing a couple thousand rows, you can do a loop instead if you are more familiar with that one.

Comment: dataframes are of different length.Kindly help me with loop

Comment: Map the values of the bihger datframe to the smaller dataframe and do the above code on the smaller dataframe. So you'll want to create a new column on the smaller dataframe using `map` with `fillna` parameter equal to a default value (ie. just the original value of a column). Then do the comparison using `where`. That's generally faster to avoid looping.